# uicollectionview cells not showed after updates as per requirement after reload data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

i have a products catalogue that is shown in **collection view**, User may change the **category** or **sub category** for new products and they are populating in **collection view** perfectly.

now user may choose the **quantity** of any specific product in numbers as 1, 2, 3 or more to buy.
for this i set **UIButton** action in collection view cell to take users input in **UITextfield** inside Cell.

all works perfectly, actually i have different number of products as per Category wise, and most of the time i have to **scroll** to see products in **collection view**.

when ever the quantity of any product or more than one products are set they are just perfect as i want in each **Cell**.

** Updated Problem:**

if i change the category or sub category to see other **products** in **collection view** now this condition never satisfies in both **uibutton** action method and in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method. 
here is problem:

```
if ([code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i])
{} // this condition is creating problem on category or sub category change.
```

that how i am working:

Custom CollectionView class

```
@interface MyCell  : UICollectionViewCell
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *btn1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *txt1;
@end
```

implementation

```
@implementation MyCell
@synthesize btn1, txt1;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    CGRect btn1Rect = CGRectMake(190, 230 , 35 , 35);
    btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btn1Rect];
    btn1.tag=11;
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPlus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //btn1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    CGRect txt1Rect = CGRectMake(143, 230 , 45 , 30);
    txt1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:txt1Rect];
    txt1.tag=13;
    txt1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Superclarendon" size:18];
    txt1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    txt1.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    //txt1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
 }
 return self;
}
```

in ViewController implementation

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[[cell btn1] addTarget:self action:@selector( btnPlus:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.btn1];
cell.txt1.text = @"0";
for (i = 0; i < [updatedCodes count]; i++)
{
    if ([code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i])
    {
        cell.txt1.text = [updatedQty objectAtIndex:i];
     }
}
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.txt1];
return cell;
}
```

the UIButton Action Method is

```
-(void)btnPlus:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:myCollection];
btnIndex = [myCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[myCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:btnIndex];
NSString *newCode = [code objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row];
NSString *newQty = cell.txt1.text;
if ([updatedCodes containsObject:newCode])
{
    for (i = 0; i < [updatedCodes count]; i ++)
    {
        if ([updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i] == newCode)
        {
            qnty = [newQty integerValue];
            qnty = qnty + 1;
            cell.txt1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", qnty];
            newQty = cell.txt1.text;
            [updatedQty replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newQty];
        }
    }
    if (![indexPaths containsObject:btnIndex])
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:btnIndex];
    }
}
else
{
    [updatedCodes addObject:newCode];
    qnty = [newQty integerValue];
    qnty = qnty + 1;
    cell.txt1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", qnty];
    newQty = cell.txt1.text;
    [updatedQty addObject:newQty];
    if (![indexPaths containsObject:btnIndex])
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:btnIndex];
    }
}
[myCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
}
```

NOTE:
Code, indexPaths ,updatedCodes and updatedQty are **NSMutableArrays**

Any suggestion / Help about this problem will be greatly appreciated.

waiting for swift help….. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering your own question may be not good but i figured out my problem and resolve it myself

so posting here the issue for some one else who is suffering in same problem….

this is all i change in my code

in view controller implemention

```
if ([code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i])
{
    cell.txt1.text = [updatedQty objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

with this

```
if ([[code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:[updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i]])
    {
        cell.txt1.text = [updatedQty objectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

and same change in Button Action method as

```
if ([newCode isEqualToString:[updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i]])
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
if ([indexPaths count] > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < [updatedCodes count]; i++)
    {
        if ([code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i])
        {
            cell.txt1.text = [updatedQty objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
}
```

As when this array has records it will go in within this IF statement and will skip the else statement where you are actually setting your cell.txt1.text = @"0". Easiest fix would be to put next line of code just before the for loop

```
cell.txt1.text = @"0";
```

Like this

```
if ([indexPaths count] > 0)
    { 
        cell.txt1.text = @"0";
        for (i = 0; i < [updatedCodes count]; i++)
        {
            if ([code objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == [updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i])
            {
                cell.txt1.text = [updatedQty objectAtIndex:i];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: issue is same…. actually this text value for example '4' for one product and '3' for another one also shown up some other cells too .:(

Comment: Why you're calling this `[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.txt1];` before `return cell;` and where is this object created?

Comment: txt1 is created in cell's custom class. and i think here is the place to show uitextfiled inside the cell before return cell;

Comment: remove `else
{
    cell.txt1.text = @"0";
}` and put `cell.txt1.text = @"0";` just before `if ([indexPaths count] > 0)`

Comment: on category or sub category change the **CollectionView** is reloaded it works perfectly but if i back on same category again this time all textfield are '0' again

Comment: because on reloading i am re initialising the array of indexpaths.

Comment: if i don't do this then in case of cells count < indexpaths count,,, the app crashes with error that attempt to delete item that is beyonds the boundry

Comment: to be quite honest your code is a bit messy. You are initializing arrays all over the place and its very hard to understand the purpose behind it. You can simply create `NSMutableDictionary` and set its key to hold the indexpath and its value to qty. So you will anly have to check if a key exsist in your dictionary or not instead of creating all this array. This is just my oppinion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52693/discussion-between-panayot-panayotov-and-zaibi)